# PHP Calendar with expired date in new div

Tags: php, mysql, database, date

I'm creating a calendar/schedule for a client, it's kinda rough since I'm a frontend developer and complete new with php.

This is what I got: http://www.nrg-agency.com/events/

The script is real basic, and it was sorted on most far date first, which I got working now that the upcoming date is sorted on top.

My question is, how could I create that the past events automatically will go in a new div under the schedule with "Past Events"?

This is what I got in my "Functions.php" file:

```
<?php

function init_db(){

   global $db;

   $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $db[db]";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);

   $buildNow = 'yes';

   while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
               if($row[0] == 'joe_cal_events'){
                  $buildNow = 'no';
               }
   }

   if($buildNow == 'yes'){
      mysql_query("
      CREATE TABLE `joe_cal_events` (
                          `id` mediumint(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                          `start` date NOT NULL default '2014-30-04',
                          `end` date NOT NULL default '2020-01-01',
                          `title` text NOT NULL,
                          `url` text NOT NULL,
                          `description` text NOT NULL,
                          PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
                        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
      ") or die(mysql_error());
   }

}
foreach ($dataArray as $key => $row) {
    $orderByDate[$key]  = strtotime($row['start']);
}

array_multisort($orderByDate, SORT_ASC, $dataArray);

array_multisort($orderByDate, SORT_ASC, $dataArray);

function prettyDate($date,$type){
   list($y,$m,$d) = explode("-", $date);
   if($type == 1){
      return "$m/$d/$y";
   }
   if($type == 2){
      return(date("j F Y",mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d,$y)));
   }
}

?>
```

And this in my events.php:

```
<body>

";


$q = mysql_query("select * from joe_cal_events order by start asc");
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)){

   print "
   <div class='feedEkList'><li>
   <div class='itemTitle'>$r[title]</div>
   <div class='itemdate'>".prettyDate($r[start],2)."</div>
   ";
   if($r[description]){
      print "<div class='itemText'>$r[description]</div>";
   }
   print "
   </li>
   </div>
   ";
}

print "
</div>
</body>
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through your array.

```
$pastevents = array();
$futureevents = array();

foreach($events as $event) {
    if(strtotime($event['date']) < time()) {
       $pastevents[] = $event;
    } else {
       $futureevents[] = $event;
}
```

Now you have two arrays, one containing your past, and one containing your future events.

In your case replace:

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
```

with:

```
$pastevents = array();
$futureevents = array();

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    if(strtotime($r['date']) < time()) {
        $pastevents[] = $r;
    } else {
        $futureevents[] = $r;
    }
}

foreach($futureevents as $event) {
   // your display logic
}

foreach($pastevents as $event) {
    // your display logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! But as I said I'm complete new with PHP.

Could you please take a look at my code? And how would I add this to the HTML?

Comment: @MBouwman I've updated my reply. I use full words like $event instead of $r, because it is more readable. When another programmer sees the code he'll easier understand.